# Powershell - Exclude P: Drive from foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, diskspace

I have a script that goes through a text file of servers and reports on free disk space under 25% and 10%. However some servers have a P: drive which is used for a paging file, and therefore I wish the loop to ignore this drive.

Here is the loop part:

```
# Start processing disk space reports against a list of servers 
  foreach($computer in $computers) 
 {  
 $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3" -EA SilentlyContinue
 $computer = $computer.toupper() 
  foreach($disk in $disks) 
 {         
  $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID; 
        $volName = $disk.VolumeName; 
  [float]$size = $disk.Size; 
  [float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace;  
  $percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100, 2); 
  $sizeGB = [Math]::Round($size / 1073741824, 2); 
  $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($freespace / 1073741824, 2); 
        $usedSpaceGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB; 
        $color = $whiteColor;
```

I'm at a very basic level with powershell, so any help with the syntax and how to exclude the P: drive would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a condition to the WMI filter to exclude volumes with `DeviceID = P:`:

```
$disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3 AND DeviceID != 'P:'" -ComputerName $computer -EA SilentlyContinue
```

---

Alternatively, filter the `$disks` collection with `Where-Object`:

```
foreach($disk in $disks |Where-Object {$_.DeviceID -ne 'P:'}) 
{
    # ...
}
```